# What is the best way to create a class object and reuse it in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Im new to the c# and I have C# application which can print Bills. in that case I use Class (`Billprint`) to create the bill. after open the application it print bills contentiously, still the application working fine but I need to know the way of doing this correct or not or if it is wrong how to fix. to use that Bill class I use following code,

```
List<Receipt> order;
            order = LoadReceiptData();
            SessionData.setBillamount();

            Billprint bill = new Billprint(order, SessionData.lastbillamout, SessionData.tabel, 1);
```

is it necessary to check the `bill` object exists or not before creating it ? and how to do that.

Comment: Your best bet is to pick up a [How to program with c# book](http://www.amazon.com) and start at chapter 1. You will not learn how to program (well) by trial and error and posting a question about everything you come across on [so].

Comment: _"...is it necessary to check the object exists or not before creating it ?..."_ - that makes zero sense.  Is it necessary to check whether a house exists before creating it?

Comment: may be my language is not good... but Im expecting a answer.  any one could understand what Im try to say. what is my real problem pls post a answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of options.

1) You could simply create a new bill each time, e.g. when a user clicks `PrintBill()`. Something like this

```
private void PrintBill(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Billprint bill = new BillPrint(...);
}
```

2) If only having one is important then you could look at implementing the [singleton](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) pattern and then updating your bill before you print each one. Something like this

```
public class Billprint
{
   private static Billprint instance;

   private Billprint() {}

   public static Billprint Instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Billprint();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }

   public void UpdateBill(...)
   {
        // Update your bill
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By "print bills contentiously" I think you mean "print bills continuously", and by "is it necessary to check the object exists or not before creating it" I think you mean "is it necessary to check that I already have a bill (Billprint) object before I create a new one?".

Consider this:

```
while (true)
{
    Billprint bill = new Billprint(order, SessionData.lastbillamout, SessionData.tabel, 1);
}
```

Each time around the loop a new Billprint object is created and assigned to bill; when bill goes out of scope (at the end of the loop), it no longer has any references to it and is therefore available to be automatically freed by the garbage detector at some point in the future (we do not need to worry about when this is).

So to answer your question, it is not necessary to check whether you already have a Billprint object - if you no longer need it, you can just forget about it and the garbage collector will automatically clean it up.